# Agregar evento resize a un qwidget pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo el siguiente problema:

estoy diseñando una interfaz de usuario para un programa, sin embargo no utilice un mainwindow ya que no encontré la manera de reducir el tamaño de el qstatusbar

Asi que lo estoy realizando sobre un qwidget, el problema es que al eliminar los marcos de la ventana `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` no puedo cambiar el tamaño de el widget, como lo aria en una venta normal con marco.

alguna solución?

Codigo .py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, Qt, QtGui

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("23.ui",self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)





app = QApplication([])
p = Widget()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

codigo .ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>principal</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="principal">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>595</width>
    <height>418</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 211), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 221));</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>120</width>
     <height>421</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background:blue;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Hola Revsky01, he visto tu pregunta anterior sobre la barra de estado, efectivamente no es simple porque QMainWindows está pensada para usar un widget central que está al mismo nivel que la StatusBar, por lo que el Frame se mantendrá dentro del widget central aunque redimensiones la barra. Ahora bien, ¿Si la barra de estado de QMainWindow es el problema porqué no la eliminas simplemente?

Comment: @FJSevilla, el problema es que al eliminar la barra de estado en el QMainWindow se me presenta el mismo problema por que no puedo re-dimensionar el MainWindow ya que también elimine el marco

Comment: He creado una respuesta basada en incluir un  QSizeGrip en la esquina inferior derecha como tiene la barra de estado de QMainwindow, existe otra posibilidad que es creando manualmente un borde a la ventana que permita redimensionar de forma similar a como hace el gestor de ventanas pero es algo más complicado y no tengo demasiado tiempo ahora por desgracia, intentaré agregarlo cuando pueda si nadie da una respuesta similar. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla, te agradeceria mucho si pudieras agregar la otra solución para reforzar conocimientos y como otra herramienta mas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente al aplicar `QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint` eliminamos las funciones propias del decorador de ventanas del SO, lo cual conlleva la imposibilidad de realizar las funciones que este provee como redimensionar usando los bordes de la ventana, las funciones de los  botones de maximizado, minimizado y cierre o arrastrar y soltar la ventana en una posición determinada.

Otra forma muy simple de redimensionar la ventana en este caso es usando un `QSizeGrip` como el que posee la barra de estado de `QMainWindow`.

Si no puedes usar el `QSizeGrip` de la barra de estado de `QMainWindows` dada la dificultad que comentas de redimensionar esta y que el frame ocupe el espacio dejado tienes varias opciones.

Siguiendo tu propio ejemplo puedes usar un `QWidget` de base aunque en este caso debes crear manualmente la instancia de `QSizeGrip` y agregarlo al widget en la posición adecuada. Basado en tu propio ejemplo pero usando un `QGridLAyout` y dos `QFrame`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 300)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred
                                           )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background:blue;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred
                                           )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 211), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 221));")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)

        sizeGrip= QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, 1, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)


        # Centrar widget en la ventana
        qt_rect = self.frameGeometry()
        center_point = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qt_rect.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.move(qt_rect.topLeft())

        self.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Otra opción muy simple es usar un `QDialog` que también tiene la posibilidad de habilitar su `QSizeGrip` en la esquina inferior derecha mediante el método `QDialog.setSizeGripEnabled`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 300)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred
                                           )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background:blue;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred
                                           )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 211), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 221));")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)

        self.setSizeGripEnabled(True)

        self.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

El resultado es similar en ambos casos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por la solución fantástico como siempre